# python: creating a dictionary, coming up as "None" in a file

Tags: python, dictionary

when reading the file it is coming up as "None", how can i fix this so that it is a dictionary(made from two varibles) in a file.

```
with open('RPS.txt','r') as f:
    highscores = [line.strip() for line in f]
    f = open('RPS.txt','a')
    high = {player_score: name}
    highscores = highscores.append(high)
    print(highscores, file=f)
    f.close()
```

Comment: you cannot open the same file twice

Comment: i fixed it with f.close() after the second line... still have same problem

Comment: @gdlmx - sure you can. It might not do what you want but in this case if OP just wants to read and append the file, it will work.

Comment: There are some basic code smells here: opening the same file twice, using the same variable name both times the file is opened, creating the high & highscores objects inside the routine that outputs them.

Comment: What is `None`? Nothing is `None` in this script. Please show us the exact error. And please make this a runnable example - not a zillion lines of code, just enough to demonstrate. You never write the file so what's the point in reopening it in append mode?

Comment: Open the file with 'rw' permission once, fix the `highscores=...` error

Comment: Also: if you've updated the code (i.e. added `f.close()` after the second line) please update your question with the new code.

Comment: tdelaney, when i print the file it literally comes up as "None" in the shell

Comment: @gdlmx that mode works for python 2 but not 3. `"a+"` is another option.

Answer (score 3):

```
highscores = highscores.append(high)
```

This set highscores to None.
append returns None, do not set it to your variable.

Comment: how does this set highscore to none? shouldnt it set it to a dictionary?

Comment: append() returns nothing, it modifies the list object.

Comment: And he overwrites highscore with the append result, which is nothing, but None.